# How change img src in cloned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main `div` with another `div` and `img` like this

```js
$(".source_next_box")
  .clone()
  .removeClass('source_next_box')
  .find('img')
  .attr('src', data.url)
  .insertAfter(".next_box:last");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next_box"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4 source_next_box">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top preview-img" src="img/preview.png">
    <div class="card-body pos-relative">
      <h6 class="card-title mb-3">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link remove-files" data-id="77"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need clone this div with class `source_next_box` and put into `next_box` but with remove `next_box` class, and change `src` to show image and change `data-id` in button.

but on result i have

```
<div class="next_box"></div>
<img src="new_img_link>
```

What i need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using chaining when you perform `.find('img').attr()` you are refering to `<IMG>` element, hence it is getting appended to DOM.

You need to use [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

```
$(".source_next_box")
    .clone()
    .removeClass('source_next_box')
    .find('img')
    .attr('src', data.url)
    .end() //<============
    .insertAfter(".next_box:last");
```

```js
$(".source_next_box")
  .clone()
  .removeClass('source_next_box')
  .find('img')
  .attr('src', "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/64272f530b4465cf2c8821156ddab99c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")
  .end()
  .insertAfter(".next_box:last");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="next_box"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4 source_next_box">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top preview-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/64272f530b4465cf2c8821156ddab99c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <div class="card-body pos-relative">
      <h6 class="card-title mb-3">Title</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link remove-files" data-id="77">button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```